# Tool to provide a graph for C source code files

Tags: c, modeling

I have 3 files of C language code and their 2 header files. I would like to see the dependency graph of all functions getting called in these 3 files. Is there a tool on Windows to simplify this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already tried [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) in combination with the graphviz package?